# Applyonpoint Error 1 Inconsistent accessibility:

Tags: c#

```
public Point2D ApplyOnPoint(Point2D point)
{
  return ApplyOnPoint(matrix, point);
 }
```

> Error  1   Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'hw4.Point2D' is less accessible than method 'hw4.TransformationMatrix.ApplyOnPoint(hw4.Point2D)'    G:\home\יסומים\hw4\hw4\TransformationMatrix.cs  49  24  hw4

Comment: You need to give more information. and a sentence or two at least. Just a code dump is not effective communication.

Comment: Did you go look at the accessibility (public/private/internal...) or the place it told you to look?

Comment: Error   1   Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'hw4.Point2D' is less accessible than method 'hw4.TransformationMatrix.ApplyOnPoint(hw4.Point2D)'    G:\home\יסומים\hw4\hw4\TransformationMatrix.cs  49  24  hw4

Comment: And what is the accessibility level of `ApplyOnPaint`?

Comment: I'm guessing you haven't set  Point2D class to be `public/internal`.. impossible to be certain without any relevant code

Answer (score 1):

it looks like `Point2D` is not a `public class`.  It looks like it should be one though.

```
public Point2D
{
  ...
```